# How do I manually POST JSON data with only an ssh connection (no cURL or other utility)

Tags: http, command-line, openssh

I want to manually POST JSON data using just a keyboard and ssh connection (i.e. without cURL). The cURL functionality I'm trying to replicate which works great is equivalent to:

```
curl -s -w '\n' -X POST -D - \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}' \
  https:///myserver.com/mypath
```

However, when I connect manually:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:443 -quiet
```

and then enter

```
POST /mypath HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Content-type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2"
}
```

I get the message "Json content error HV000116: The object to be validated must not be null." I've tried every variation I can think of with whitespace, and encoding, but I still get the error. I know I'm missing something simple, but what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Just needed to add the Content-length header and everything worked